# MinGW GCC compiles a faulty code without warning or error

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

Can you explain to me why doesn't MingW GCC produce warning in this code:

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int people[ num ];
    cout << people[ 0 ];
    cin >> num;
}
```

But here, I only replaced the last statement with `num = 1` and now there is a warning...

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int people[ num ];  //warning: 'num is used uninitialized..'
    cout << people[ 0 ];
    num = 1;
}
```

Comment: Wait, so, is the warning there at all or not? I edited but had to roll your question back because it contradicts itself.

Comment: @BoltClock: Edit: Oh wait, never mind, the question contradicts itself... I edited the question, that's what it should be.

Comment: What's surprising me is that *either* of them compiles, considering that the array size should be a constant...

Comment: I overlooked that the compiler flag -w (inhibit all warning messages) was actually set. I can't believe that I just spent a whole day figuring it out. Sorry! How do I delete this thread?

Comment: @cursebox: Did you get a warning *without* -w? I even compiled your code with `-Wall` and still got no warning...

Comment: Yes, after I unchecked -w the warning showed. It says "ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'people'". But there's no warning about the uninitialized variable num. oh no!

Comment: @Mehrdad: This is a GCC extension, and probably you have to use `-ansi` or `-std=c++98`.

Comment: Non-constant length arrays are perfectly allowable in gcc outside strict mode, this is a GNU extension. Though this particular case is truly funny, because since `num` isn't initialized, it's more or less random whether or not you'll provoke a stack overflow with this.

Comment: @Philipp: I used `-std=c++0x`...

Comment: @sehe: Why the `[RESOLVED]` edit? It doesn't look resolved to me... there's no warning in `-std=c++0x` mode.

Comment: Sorry, this is just too confusing. I responded to "_I overlooked that the compiler flag -w (inhibit all warning messages) was actually set. I can't believe that I just spent a whole day figuring it out. Sorry! How do I delete this thread?_". Perhaps a cleanup of mis-guided or obsolete comments is in order, or an **conspicuously updated question**?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Seems that it also needs `-pedantic`.

Comment: @mehrdad : according to cursebox himself, he wants to delete the thread cause the error is not what ihe thought ?

Comment: Can someone that understands the comment trail make an answer out of it (or flag/vote for delete) - reads like some comments are deleted, and there's much confusion for all?

Answer (score 2):

I think because you are only using the first element, it optimizes out the num in the first example. It just creates a single element array. In the second case since you actually use the num, it gives the error

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int people[ num ];
    cout << people[ 0 ];
    cin >> num;
}
```

will only produce an error  (in fact a warning) in g++ if the `-pedantic` flag is used. The warning is:

```
ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'people'
```

which is correct. The use of variable length arrays is a GCC extension, which is turned off by `-pedantic`. Note that successful compilation with `-std=whatever` does not guarantee your code complies with that standard - the -`std` flag is used to turn features on, not disable them.